# CSS - Style specific to single Element

Tags: css, margins

I'm using jQuery to add a Class to a few elements.

I'm not new to adding classes, nor removing them.  But I'm still somewhat intermediate with styles and any flexibility styles can perform to single elements.

Here's what's going on:

I have 2 Divs that I'm affecting with jQuery:

```
<div id="columnleft">stuff in here</div>
<div id="columncenter">bigger stuff in here</div>
```

In a nutshell, column left is about 155px wide, while columncenter is positioned relative to columnleft, with a margin-left of 162px

Here's my styles:

```
<style>
#columnleft {
  float:left; 
  position:relative;
  text-align:left;
  width:155px; 
}

#columncenter {  
  position:relative; 
  padding-bottom:50px
  margin:0; 
  margin-left:162px; 
}
</style>
```

I'm basically toggling these 2 divs with the jQuery examples below:

So far I've gotten these 2 separate instances to work:

```
$("#columnleft").hide();
$("#columncenter").css("margin","0px");
```

then........

```
$("#columnleft").show();
$("#columncenter").css("margin-left","162px");
```

Though this works, I'm not quite satisfied.
I'd prefer to create a class or two that I can use to toggle the hiding of columnleft, while also changing the margin-left at the same time.

It's all fine with the example above, when I'm only using jQuery.  But there are times when a page loads, and the columnleft is meant to be hidden, and columncenter is meant to be expanded, from the beginning.  Would be nice to not need jQuery to enter the scene at those moments.

All I could come up with is:

```
<style>
.disappear { display:none; }
.maximize { margin:0px;  margin-left:0px; }
</style>
```

When the page loads:

```
<div id="columnleft" class="disappear">stuff in here</div>
<div id="columncenter" class="maximize">bigger stuff in here</div>
```

it seems that columncenter is ignored.  (columnleft indeed does disappear)
Also, toggling with jquery, the same result occurs.

Column Center hates me!
Does anyone see where I'm missing the mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**View JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/tuanderful/bTZq8/

What if you had another `div` that contains both `#columnleft` and `#columncenter`, and has a class of `.hide-left` or `.show-left`:

```
<div class="hide-left">
    <div id="columnleft">stuff in here</div>
    <div id="columncenter">bigger stuff in here</div>
</div>
```

​
Then add the following CSS:

```
.show-left #columnleft {
    display: block;
}
.show-left #columncenter {
    margin-left: 162px; 
}

.hide-left #columnleft {
    display: none;
}
.hide-left #columncenter {
    margin-left: 0; 
}
```

You can update your jQuery to simply toggle the `.hide-left` or `.show-left` classes on the parent container.

What I did here is similar to adding `.disappear` and `.maximize` styling, but I added a bit of context around the two columns. The neat thing is that all of the styling is handled purely by CSS - when you want to show or hide your sidebar, you only need JavaScript to update the state of the container; that is, change the class in the container from hide to show or vice versa.

Comment: Funny you mention the extra div. I actually had that, but didn't think to mention it.  You made a very good point.
I needed to see your examples to give me a decent view of how the css only affects those 2 divs.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `!important` on the css styling.

```
.maximize {
  margin-left: 0px !important;
}
```

That makes it so that it overrides any other styling of the same kind. [**Check it out here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/gCRP2/)

There is an order of importance in CSS. An id `#` is considered more important than a class `.` (there can only be one id and many classes after all). So if you are trying to override an id with a class, you need to use `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

each type of selector in css is weighted differently id being higher than classes and classes being higher than objects

to fix your problem make the selector as such

```
#columncenter.maximize
```

this will overwrite the rule before it

don't use `!important` while it might work now it can be hard to find out why something is being overridden later on

Comment: Wouldn't `#columncenter.maximize` be harder to realize why your styling is being overridden? Especially if using this method in hundreds of lines of styling? Whereas if you used `!important`, you could look for the `!important` keyword and quickly realize where the problem is...